# symbol can be passed as a formal argument in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols

i have tried to used symbols and even instance variable as formal argument, but ruby gives error

> syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting ')'
>
> def callMe(:value)

so how does form_for in rails manages to use symbols and instance variables as first parameter

```
<% form_for(@user) do |f| %> ... <% end %>
```

OR

```
<% form_for(:user) do |f| %> ... <% end %>
```

Below is the code which i am trying to execute.

```
class Demo

attr_accessor :name, :surname

def initialize(name,surname)
    @name = name
    @surname = surname
    
end

def printThis
    puts name
    puts surname
     
    callMe(name)
    
end
    
    def callMe(:value)
        puts :value
    end
    
end

d = Demo.new('abc','pqr')

d.printThis
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter should not be a symbol when you define your function, only when you call it. Try again with `callMe` defined like

```
def callMe(value)
    p value.class
end

callMe(:test)
```

Comment: So even if we pass :test as parameter it will assign "test" as a value rather than value :test symbol is pointing to, right?

Comment: I believe it should still by a symbol inside the function. Give this updated code a try.

Comment: When it is written outside class it prints Symbol, but when inside a class it gives error